# How to setup outlook rules for blog emails eg wordpress.com

Tags: email, rules, microsoft-outlook-365

Using Outlook 365 and wanting to setup separate rules for wordpress.com blogs.
ie  Blog A donotreply@wordpress.com,  Blog B donotreply@wordpress.com

Can setup the rules as follows but not working.  Have added both Blog A and Blog B  in local contacts despite same email address.

[image]

Actual email values in local contacts as per screenshot:
Chris Webb's BI Blog donotreply@wordpress.com,
RADACAD donotreply@wordpress.com

And text to search for in senders address: 'Chris Webb', 'RADACAD'

[image]

Using the mouse menu 'Always Move Messages From: ...' option will work but places emails from both A and B into A or B rule folder depending on which email is highlighted at time of run.

### Link to closest forum thread  [Outlook rule does not recognize sender](https://superuser.com/questions/1240660/outlook-rule-does-not-recognize-sender)

6-sep-2023
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by referencing the Message Header rather than From address in Outlook.

Start with a blank receive rule, and then select `with specific words in the message header`. Click on `specific words` and add the display name you want the rule to apply to, for instance "Blog A" or "Blog B". Finish creating the rule as usual and repeat for each blog you want to have a rule for.

Edited to add screenshots of how the rule should roughly look.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Keith, no go unfortunately.  See screenshot of testing added to original post under 6-sep-2023.

Comment: @GaryThomann that new screenshot shows you're checking `with "Chris Webb" in the subject` NOT the Message Header. I'll add a couple of screenshots of how it should look.